# Git Merge Conflict Custom Auto-Resolution

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Is there any way to write a custom merge conflict resolver in git?  We are having evil merge conflicts resulting from changing java import statements on multiple branches.  These seem like they would be fairly easy to write a plugin to handle automatically 90% of the time.  Does git have hooks that would allow us to write custom auto-merge behavior for just this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new merge strategy in `.gitconfig` as described [here](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-tricks-tips-workflows/).

```
[merge "mymergescheme"]
        name = my awesome merger
        driver = "my_executable_here"
```

You can then specify that merge strategy for particular files inside `.gitattributes` as described at the same page.

```
src/*.java merge=mymergescheme
```

Comment: This looks close to what I need, but is there any way to retain git's default merge strategy?  Like invoke it after I run mine or something?

Comment: @xdhmoore, Not that I am aware of, although you could probably hack something. Note that the semantics will be tricky because git expects the output of the initial merge to already be a correctly merged file.

Comment: Found the docs [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver).  Perhaps I could return an error code, but I'm not sure if that invokes another automerge strategy.

Comment: @xdhmoore, Good job. I hope those will sufficiently address your issue in more detail than this answer can.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [git rerere](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html) command that is intended to resolve a conflict once and then have git resolve similar future conflicts in the same way. I do not have experience in using this myself, and I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but I suspect this should be worth considering/testing out.